# Unexpected submit on "submit" button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I make submit button active (with <kbd>Tab</kbd> button), and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, keypress handler will fire, and will generate click event on button. But `OnClick` and Submit handlers will not fire. It'll just silently post the form. Why?

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

$().ready(function(){
     $("#f1").keypress(function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode==13){
            var currentInputId = $(event)[0].target.id;
            var currentInput = $('#'+currentInputId);
            currentInput.click();
            return false;
          }
      });


  $("#f1").submit(function(){
   alert ("huy")
  })
})
</script>
<form name="f1" id="f1" method="POST">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You can just do this: `var currentInput = $(event.target);` instead of re-looking up the element by its "id" value.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer rewritten from scratch

On my machine what happens in your scenario (move input on submit button, then press ENTER) is:

- `keypress` handler runs and calls `click` on the button
- button `onclick` returns `false`
- event handling stops (form is not submitted)

If I remove the `onclick="return false;"`, then:

- `keypress` handler runs and calls `click` on the button
- form is submitted *without* the `submit` handler being called

A few more tests indicate that the `submit` handler is not being called *because you return `false` from the `keypress` handler.

So, to solve the issue:

1. Remove `onclick="return false;"` from the button
2. Remove `return false` from the `keypress` handler

This will display the alert and then submit the form as you expect it to.

Comment: Thanx. But I still don't understand, why the `onsubmit` handler does not fire, because it defined as jQuery's submit handler.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I tested the code ONLY with button being active. Button HAS `id` attribute, and keypress handler works properly in than case. So form posts, and submit handler still doesn't fire.

Comment: @ataman: I don't know why the form posts for you. It's not the button that needs an `id`, it's the text input because *that* is what `event.target` refers to.

Comment: :) `event.target` refers to test input only in case when text input is active (has focus) while `Enter` pressed. But the bug is actual for button, not the edit. So I press `Enter` while button HAS FOCUS. And then `event.target` refers to button, and click event succesfully sent to button.

Comment: @ataman: Sorry, I misunderstood :) Here's another update, hope this makes things clear.

Comment: It's strange behavior, that returning `false` in keypress handler cancels execution of submit handler. I'd like to read some documentation on this behavior. Strange that on my machine(FF4, Chrome) form submits even if `onclick="return false;"` handler present. And, at last: if we remove 'return false' from the 'keypress' handler form will submit because of default behavior of browser(enter pressed on form), not because i explicitly trigger click event.

Comment: You see, in my code form submits when i call `currentInput.click();`. So, if I even remove `return false` from keypress handler, it will submit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think, the only left question "why submit handler does't fire" is the question to jQuery team.